# Is there a Keyboard Shortcut to Select Windows 7 Login Name?

Tags: windows-7

Given the following logon screen:

[image]

Is there a way I can select *MyUserName* with a keyboard shortcut?

Alternatively, can I change this screen to look like the network login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as using arrow keys.

As for the second part, is [this](http://windows7themes.net/enable-classic-logon-screen-in-windows-7.html) what you wanted?

Comment: Or use the Tab key, and press Enter.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex Heh, I didn't know that one.  Learning something new all the time.

Comment: I wonder what other keys did the OP try **besides** the arrow keys.  HJKL?

Comment: For some odd reason, I was trying Ctrl + F1/1, Alt + F1/1...don't know why that didn't occur to me. :P    And yes, that link aptly describes what I ultimately wanted to do.  So TYVM.